# Going about sharing 2FA key between multiple login methods on a Synology NAS + browser & SSH authentication

Tags: ssh, multi-factor, server

I've recently acquired a Synology server (DS720+) and have it accessible outside my LAN via a VPN. I have 2FA on for logins to the server via the web portal, but I have found many use cases for connecting via SSH. Is there a way to secure SSH with 2FA while using the same 2FA 'entry' for the Synology quick-connect web portal? Does this even make sense to do, or would I be far better served by simply using 2FA for the portal and a private + public key arrangement for SSH?

Comment: Consider that most 2FA's are on the order of 6-digit numbers and I think you have your answer.